# Swift - Change background color in tableView.selectRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView that has all the correct behaviors, but I am trying to change the background color of a selected row from the default grey to green and the tableView is acting strange.

Current behavior with default color: page loads and the first row of the first table section is selected as default (grey background). If user clicks another row, the first one is deselected and the one clicked gets the grey background. This code:

```
private var scrolledToItitialSelection = false
didSet {
    tableView.reloadData()
    if let selected = self.model.selectedRow { // selectedRow returns an indexPath
        tableView.selectRow(at: selected, animated: true, scrollPosition: scrolledToInitialSelection ? .none : .middle

        scrolledToItitialSelection = true
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve the exact same behavior, only with a different background color. But with the code bellow, the tableView loads and the first row of the first table section is selected as expected, but so is the second row of the second section. Also, if I click the row bellow the one selected by default, now I have 4 selected rows: two in the first section, two in the second.

```
private var scrolledToItitialSelection = false
didSet {
    tableView.reloadData()
    if let selected = self.model.selectedRow { // selectedRow returns an indexPath
        tableView.selectRow(at: selected, animated: true, scrollPosition: scrolledToInitialSelection ? .none : .middle
        let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selected)!
        selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
        selectedCell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = .green
        scrolledToItitialSelection = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. It's pretty dangerous to manipulate cells outside of `cellForRowAt` unless you know what you're doing .

Comment: @vadian Thank you, but that didn't help me with this particular problem.

Comment: @paco8 Simple: Don't manipulate cells, but invalidate rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selection color of a `UITableViewCell` is background color on a subview of the cell.

You can try with this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

/// dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundColorView
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! You made my quarantine a lot happier :-)